# Multiple form submit

Tags: 7, forms

I have a table of information displayed on a page. Each row of this table has its own submit button. I need to be able to pass information depending on what submit button is pressed.

The form is built like

```
function numberSubmit_form ($form, &$from_submit){
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
    return $form;
}
```

The rows of the table are built like:

```
$unvalRows[] = array(
            array('data' => '0'.substr($a[0], 2)),
            array('data' => drupal_render(drupal_get_form('numberSubmit_form'))),
        );
```

How am I able to determine which submit button has been used and pass the applicable phone number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the phone number as an argument to numberSubmit_form and include it in your form array:

```
$unvalRows[] = array(
    array('data' => '0'.substr($a[0], 2)),
    array('data' => drupal_render(drupal_get_form('numberSubmit_form', $phone_number))),
);
```

Then in the form constructor:

```
function numberSubmit_form ($form, &$from_submit, $phone_number){
    $form['phone_number'] = array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => $phone_number,
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
    return $form;
}
```

It will then be available to you in the submit handler:

```
function numberSubmit_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // do something with $form_state['values']['phone_number']
}
```

Comment: You are right, @dooffas's approach was wrong, as he wanted to get the submit button's data... But I think using radio buttons in a form would be even easier.

Comment: It is working fine. But i want to use '#ajax' instead of normal form submit. IF i have tried '#ajax', but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as charlie except that `#value` didn't work for me; I had to put `#default_value` in the hidden field as follow:

```
$unvalRows[] = array(
    array('data' => '0'.substr($a[0], 2)),
    array('data' => drupal_render(drupal_get_form('numberSubmit_form', $phone_number))),
);


function numberSubmit_form ($form, &$from_submit, $phone_number){
    $form['phone_number'] = array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#default_value' => $phone_number,
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
    return $form;
}

function numberSubmit_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // do something with $form_state['values']['phone_number']
}
```